# Can't pass variables from one sub to another in same module

Tags: vba, excel

The code I have works great as separate procedures. I decided to combine the 2 procedures as the code is mostly the same with a few differences in which cells are copied to the array to save to different log sheets. Each Procedure has a `Inputbox` to get the year of interest (2014, 2015, 2016....) that will be used to open AND in the event the Log does not exist Save a new one from a master using the year code in the file name.

Based on a cell value I am doing an `If_Then_Else` to determine to run one procedure or both. If I run them separately as individual procedures they work fine. When I combined them I decided to call one procedure (`SaveToLog_Audit`) from inside (`SaveToLog_Replc`). I removed the Date input from (`SaveToLog_Audit`) letting (`SaveToLog_Replc`) get that date code and pass it along. I don't want to have (`SaveToLog_Audit`) ask for a date a second time as it run since I basically want it to be inobtrusive (no need to ask twice when I can pass `Ans` to it.

I have tried setting public `Ans` and used Explicit at the beginning with both procedures in same module --> didn't work. I tried Dim Ans As String after option Explicit --> Didn't work. I tried Public Ans as String --> didn't work. Pretty much I couldn't get it to pass the variable 'Ans" no matter what I tried. I'm still pretty new to coding VBA so any help would be great. Showing the basic code, only the parts that have issues.

```
 Option Explicit
 Public Ans As String

 Public Sub SaveToLog_Replc()

 '  Determine scrap and whether to save to Replacement_Credit tracking log
 Dim ScrapQty As Range
 '  Date entry for proper Dated log save
 Dim Ans As String
 Dim c As Boolean
 Dim fs As Object
 '  Declares path, newFile and fName variables
 Dim path As String, newFile As String, fName As String
 Set Sheet2 = ActiveSheet
 Set ScrapQty = Worksheets("Main").Range("M_Qty_Scrap")
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 '  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    Ans = InputBox("Enter Log Year" & _
     "" & vbCrLf, "Year Selection", Format(Date, "YYYY"))
       If Ans = "" Then
          Exit Sub
       End If
 '  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    '  If scrap qty is greater than Zero (0) save to both Logs
    If ScrapQty > 0 Then
    ' If True
       MsgBox "Saving to Replacement Log and Audit Log"
    ' xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    '    Save to Audit Log then Save to Replacement Log
      '  --> 'Ans' VALUE NEEDS TO PASS TO THE PROCEDURE
      '  --> 'Ans' DOES NOT PASS TO THIS PROCEDURE AT END OF MODULE
   Call SaveToLog_Audit
    ' xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ' +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    '  Sub routine to Save Data to Replacement Log
    '  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '     Load Array code here for SaveToLog_Replc
    '  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '  ***************************************************************
       'Check if Replacement Log exists. If not open Master, rename then save it. If it exists open it.
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        '  Filename to check for
        c = fs.fileExists("S:\RECORDS\Logs\Replacement Log " & Ans & ".xls")
          If Not c Then
             'MsgBox "The file doesn't exist!"
             '  File doesn't exist. Open the Blank Master
             Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\RECORDS\Logs\_MASTER Replacement Log.xls"
             fName = "Replacement Log " & Ans & ".xls"              ' Set fName to new FileName
             newFile = fName                                                  ' Sets new filename as fName
             path = "S:\RECORDS\Logs\"                                   ' Path to Incoming Audit Logs
             ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & newFile     ' Saves as newFile
          Else
             'MsgBox "The file exists! Saving data to it."
             Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\RECORDS\Logs\Replacement Log " & Ans & ".xls"
          End If
    '  ***************************************************************
    '  Unprotect Sheet and Show All Data code here
    '     Find LastRow. Set NextCell position code here
    '  Set the size of the new array and copy MyAr code here
    '     Draw Border Code here
    '  **********************************************
    ActiveWorkbook.Save      ' Saves Destination Workbook
    ActiveWindow.Close       ' Closes Destination Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '  Confirms Save to Log File
    MsgBox "Your Data has been saved to the Log File: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
    & "'Replacement Log " & Ans & ".xls'", vbInformation, "Log Save Confirmation"
    ' +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Else
       ' If False
       MsgBox "Saving to Audit Log Only."
    ' xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      ' Save to Audit Log as Normal
      '  --> 'Ans' VALUE NEEDS TO PASS TO THE PROCEDURE
      '  --> 'Ans' DOES NOT PASS TO THIS PROCEDURE AT END OF MODULE
   Call SaveToLog_Audit
    ' xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    End If
 End Sub

 Public Sub SaveToLog_Audit()
 '  Date entry for proper Dated log save
 Dim Ans As String
 Dim c As Boolean
 Dim fs As Object
 '  Declares path, newFile and fName variables
 Dim path As String, newFile As String, fName As String
 Set Sheet2 = ActiveSheet
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '     Load Array code here for SaveToLog_Audit
    '  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '  For debug
    '  --> 'Ans' DOES NOT PASS FROM (SaveToLog_Replc) PROCEDURE IN THIS MODULE
     MsgBox "The value of Ans is: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "'" & Ans & "'"
    '  ********************************************************
     '  Checks if Log File exists. If not open the Master, rename then save it. If it exists open it.
     Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     '  Filename to check for
     c = fs.fileExists("S:\RECORDS\Logs\" & Ans & " Audit Log.xls")
       If Not c Then
          'MsgBox "The file doesn't exist!" original code
          '  File doesn't exist. Open the Blank Master
          Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\RECORDS\Logs\_Master Audit Log.xls"
          '  Set fName to new FileName
          fName = Ans & " Audit Log.xls"
          '  Sets new filename as fName saves to this directory
          newFile = fName
          '  Path to Incoming Audit Logs
          path = "S:\RECORDS\Logs\"
          '  Saves Blank Master as newFile
          ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & newFile
       Else
          'Workbooks.Open "C:\filename.xls"
          Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
          "S:\RECORDS\Logs\" & Ans & " Audit Log.xls"
       End If
    '  ********************************************************
    '  Unprotect Sheet and Show All Data code here
    '     Find LastRow. Set NextCell position code here
    '  Set the size of the new array and copy MyAr code here
    '     Draw Border Code here
    '  **********************************************
    ActiveWorkbook.Save     ' Saves Destination Workbook
    ActiveWindow.Close      ' Closes Destination Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '  Confirms Save to Log File
    MsgBox "Your Data has been saved to the Log File: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
    & "'" & Ans & " Audit Log.xls'", vbInformation, "Log Save Confirmation"
 End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the code exactly as you posted? If yes then problem might be that you are delaring public ans then you are using dim ans in the first sub, later on you are assigning value to dim Ans not to public Ans those are made two separate variables. **Remove the dim Ans from both subroutines and it should work**

Comment: I swear I tried that on at least one of those procedures.  THAT did the trick KKowalczyk. Spent a lot of time tugging at what little hair I had left after trying about 10 ways to pass that variable.  Kudos and much THANKS.  I guess that's what I get for trying to teach myself VBA without any formal classwork. Certainly is a learning experience for sure.

Comment: No worries, you don't need any formal classes to learn vba all you need is to have enough problems to train on as I did:) PS. would be grateful for marking as answer if its the solution

Comment: I do feel that this self learning is almost better as I am doing "Practical Application" work not just sample code. Learning samples still requires one to have an idea how to apply those snippets in real working documents. I find the more I learn the more I go back and upgrade the documents I have already coded. Keeps my mind going.  Love this stuff.  I think I marked it correctly as answered to. If not I guess I am not sure how to do it.

Comment: Yes you did it right thanks:) found out the same myself tutorials werent very useful until i met exactly that problem so learning from them just in theory wasnt really useful nor fun:)

Comment: It certainly helps challenge my "learning" as the documents get into use and then I get feedback. That has helped drive my learning curve tremendously. The best part is the mass of smaller code modules/ subroutines that I just like plug-n-play in hopefully the right places to make them do what I want sometimes with small tweaks. Dealing with If-Then-Else still gets me a bit. The file works perfect now. No crashes, no hang-ups and variables pass when and where they should. I love that they pay me to learn this stuff. <Maniacal laugh>  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you remove the Public declaration and change the second routine to take a String argument:

```
Option Explicit

 Public Sub SaveToLog_Replc()

 '  Determine scrap and whether to save to Replacement_Credit tracking log
 Dim ScrapQty As Range
 '  Date entry for proper Dated log save
 Dim Ans As String
 Dim c As Boolean
 Dim fs As Object
 '  Declares path, newFile and fName variables
 Dim path As String, newFile As String, fName As String
 Set Sheet2 = ActiveSheet
 Set ScrapQty = Worksheets("Main").Range("M_Qty_Scrap")
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
 '  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    Ans = InputBox("Enter Log Year" & _
     "" & vbCrLf, "Year Selection", Format(Date, "YYYY"))
       If Ans = "" Then
          Exit Sub
       End If
 '  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
    '  If scrap qty is greater than Zero (0) save to both Logs
    If ScrapQty > 0 Then
    ' If True
       MsgBox "Saving to Replacement Log and Audit Log"
    ' xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    '    Save to Audit Log then Save to Replacement Log
      '  --> 'Ans' VALUE NEEDS TO PASS TO THE PROCEDURE
      '  --> 'Ans' DOES NOT PASS TO THIS PROCEDURE AT END OF MODULE
   Call SaveToLog_Audit(Ans)
    ' xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    ' +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    '  Sub routine to Save Data to Replacement Log
    '  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '     Load Array code here for SaveToLog_Replc
    '  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '  ***************************************************************
       'Check if Replacement Log exists. If not open Master, rename then save it. If it exists open it.
        Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
        '  Filename to check for
        c = fs.fileExists("S:\RECORDS\Logs\Replacement Log " & Ans & ".xls")
          If Not c Then
             'MsgBox "The file doesn't exist!"
             '  File doesn't exist. Open the Blank Master
             Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\RECORDS\Logs\_MASTER Replacement Log.xls"
             fName = "Replacement Log " & Ans & ".xls"              ' Set fName to new FileName
             newFile = fName                                                  ' Sets new filename as fName
             path = "S:\RECORDS\Logs\"                                   ' Path to Incoming Audit Logs
             ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & newFile     ' Saves as newFile
          Else
             'MsgBox "The file exists! Saving data to it."
             Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\RECORDS\Logs\Replacement Log " & Ans & ".xls"
          End If
    '  ***************************************************************
    '  Unprotect Sheet and Show All Data code here
    '     Find LastRow. Set NextCell position code here
    '  Set the size of the new array and copy MyAr code here
    '     Draw Border Code here
    '  **********************************************
    ActiveWorkbook.Save      ' Saves Destination Workbook
    ActiveWindow.Close       ' Closes Destination Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '  Confirms Save to Log File
    MsgBox "Your Data has been saved to the Log File: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
    & "'Replacement Log " & Ans & ".xls'", vbInformation, "Log Save Confirmation"
    ' +++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
    Else
       ' If False
       MsgBox "Saving to Audit Log Only."
    ' xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
      ' Save to Audit Log as Normal
      '  --> 'Ans' VALUE NEEDS TO PASS TO THE PROCEDURE
      '  --> 'Ans' DOES NOT PASS TO THIS PROCEDURE AT END OF MODULE
   Call SaveToLog_Audit(Ans)
    ' xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    End If
 End Sub

 Public Sub SaveToLog_Audit(Ans As String)
 '  Date entry for proper Dated log save
 Dim c As Boolean
 Dim fs As Object
 '  Declares path, newFile and fName variables
 Dim path As String, newFile As String, fName As String
 Set Sheet2 = ActiveSheet
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    '  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '     Load Array code here for SaveToLog_Audit
    '  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    '  For debug
    '  --> 'Ans' DOES NOT PASS FROM (SaveToLog_Replc) PROCEDURE IN THIS MODULE
     MsgBox "The value of Ans is: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "'" & Ans & "'"
    '  ********************************************************
     '  Checks if Log File exists. If not open the Master, rename then save it. If it exists open it.
     Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
     '  Filename to check for
     c = fs.fileExists("S:\RECORDS\Logs\" & Ans & " Audit Log.xls")
       If Not c Then
          'MsgBox "The file doesn't exist!" original code
          '  File doesn't exist. Open the Blank Master
          Workbooks.Open Filename:="S:\RECORDS\Logs\_Master Audit Log.xls"
          '  Set fName to new FileName
          fName = Ans & " Audit Log.xls"
          '  Sets new filename as fName saves to this directory
          newFile = fName
          '  Path to Incoming Audit Logs
          path = "S:\RECORDS\Logs\"
          '  Saves Blank Master as newFile
          ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=path & newFile
       Else
          'Workbooks.Open "C:\filename.xls"
          Workbooks.Open Filename:= _
          "S:\RECORDS\Logs\" & Ans & " Audit Log.xls"
       End If
    '  ********************************************************
    '  Unprotect Sheet and Show All Data code here
    '     Find LastRow. Set NextCell position code here
    '  Set the size of the new array and copy MyAr code here
    '     Draw Border Code here
    '  **********************************************
    ActiveWorkbook.Save     ' Saves Destination Workbook
    ActiveWindow.Close      ' Closes Destination Workbook
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    '  Confirms Save to Log File
    MsgBox "Your Data has been saved to the Log File: " & vbCrLf & vbCrLf _
    & "'" & Ans & " Audit Log.xls'", vbInformation, "Log Save Confirmation"
 End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your method too Rory. It does work as well. I can separate the procedures and place both in their own modules which I do like to do.